# Problem of reading numbers as factors in reading files in R

Tags: r, factors

I read many text files which each of them contains two columns: 1) names 2) real numbers. To read all files I use `lapply` function as follows:

```
Exp_data <- lapply(FileNames, function(x) read.table(file = x, fill = TRUE, skip = 2, header = F))
```

I just need the second column of files, so I get the second columns by the below instruction:

```
data <- sapply(1:length(Exp_data), function(x) Exp_data[[x]][2])
```

After running this instruction, `data` is a list of factors.
What I need to do to get a numeric matrix?

Comment: It may be that your numeric column have some character elements that makes it convert to character class. By default, stringsAsFactors=TRUE, so you get factor class.  One option will be to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and then convert the `character` class to `numeric` by `as.numeric(yourdata$yourcolumn)`, the character elements will be coerced to `NA`.  Without a reproducible example, it is not easy to comment though

Comment: You may also check if decimals are represented by `,`.  In that case, you can specify `dec=','` in the `read.table`

Comment: Thank you @akrun. You are right, some of numbers are blank in files.

Comment: If you have blank elements, it could be read as `NA` by default but I am not sure why it didn't work for you.  Perhaps, using `na.strings` would be an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has mentioned in the comments, `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` should be used in reading files, so the strings are not converted to factors anymore.